# Print dynamically generated DIV with Image through Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

i generate a image dynamically and then embed that image in a div with some text. i try to print that dynamic div with image through jquery plugin called **jquery.printElement.min.js** this plugin works fine in firefox and IE but does not work in Chrome. so here is my code which i use to print DIV.

```
 $("#Print").click(function () {
        if (ImgPath != '') {
            var ImagePath = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + ImgPath;
            alert("Your track number " + _TrackNumber);
            sHtml = "<div id=dvPrint><table>";
            sHtml += "<tr><td><img src=" + ImagePath + " height=600 width=400 border=0/></td></tr>";
            sHtml += "<tr><td>" + $('#lblTxt').html() + "</td></tr>";
            sHtml += "</table></div>";
            var $dvPrint = $(sHtml);
            $dvPrint.printElement();

        }
        else {
            alert("Image not found for print");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

i just could not figure out what is the problem in my code for which Chrome could not print rather a print preview dialog open with no image for chrome. how to sort it. do i need to use any other plugin for chrome. please guide. thanks

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but https://github.com/erikzaadi/jQueryPlugins/issues/10 : "The solution I found is to add a setTimeout to element["printPage"](); (line 105) in the _CallPrint function. " ...... `setTimeout(function () {
    element["printPage"]();
}, 50);`

Answer (score 0):

> There's a long long two years old thread at Chrome support, full of users complaining exactly how ludicrous is the lack of so basic function, as background printing, in Chrome.

With other words: Chrome does not print the background of your div.

Check out this answer for more details:

https://superuser.com/questions/117162/printing-background-colours-in-chrome